# Python stem Tor - get_newnym_wait() always return 0

Tags: python, tor, stem

I'm trying to change my Tor IP address by using stem Python library. The code below works fine (I also use it for scraping), but the get_newnym_wait() always return "0" such that I can't define relevant spleep time before requesting a new IP.

See the MWE code below (just need to set up the controller port to your own to test it).

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
from stem import CircStatus
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
from random import randint
import time
from time import sleep

def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
        controller.authenticate();
        print controller.get_newnym_wait()
        time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait());
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM);
    return;

def get_tor_exit_ip():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
        controller.authenticate()
        for circ in controller.get_circuits():
            if circ.status != CircStatus.BUILT:
                continue;
            exit_fp, exit_nickname = circ.path[-1]
            exit_desc = controller.get_network_status(exit_fp, None)
            exit_address = exit_desc.address if exit_desc else 'unknown'
        return exit_address;

a = 0
while a < 5:
    a = a + 1;
    renew_connection();
    print get_tor_exit_ip();
```

Comment: It's only ever going to return a number between 0 and 10.  If you haven't issued the signal in the last 10 seconds, then it will be 0 and no wait required.

Comment: @drew010 Thanks, but the example I provides does actually  issue the signal in the last 10 seconds and  `get_newnym_wait()` still returns 0.